# Are the react versions 0.16.4 and 16.4.x same?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, eslint, flux

If they are same, then how?
What is the exact versioning that React or facebook in general uses for all its projects such as React, ReactRouter, Flux etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most JavaScript projects use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/), so when the `x` in `16.4.x` changes, it is most often a bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

After releasing ver 0.14.7, React begins its semantic versioning along with ver 15.x.
https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/02/19/new-versioning-scheme.html

Now you can find a release blog of React ver 16.4.0: `Pointer Events`.
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/05/23/react-v-16-4.html

So 16.4.x is reasonable!

Hope this might help you.